# Does anyone know the name of this 8 pin connector?

Tags: connector

[image: name this connector]

I accidently cut this too short, does anyone know the name of this connector?

Comment: Search the JST website. Looks like one of theirs. Knowing the pitch would narrow it down a lot faster.

Comment: Looks like the XH if the pitch is 2.54mm